# How to do log tailing in realtime efficiently and in an unblocking manner in tornado python

Tags: python, logging, async-await, tornado, tail

I have a little webapp in a tornado based python project and i need to implement realtime log tailing (one of the few things i am stuck at). The behaviour shoudl be similar to unix's `tail -f`. It woudl be good if it worked on all platforms but for starters just unix is good enough.

I searched a lot of ways to do it on stackoverflow and else where but didnt find what i am looking for. Pythonic solutions are not good in keeping track of rotating logs or file being inaccessible sometimes.

Therefore i went the python `subprocess` way. However i could not use the tornado's `Subprocess` class due to lack of examples. So i have tried normal subprocess with `run_in_executor` approach. i am not sure if this is a good way to do it or if i will have future issues.

```
def tail(self, file):
        self.__process = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n", "1", "-f", file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        while 1:
            line = self.__process.stdout.readline()
            print(line)
            # call a sync marked method and push line data
            asyncio.sleep(.0001)
            if not line:
                asyncio.sleep(.5)


    async def start_tail(self):
        # start here
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(self.executor, self.tail, self.__log_path)
        pass
```

the trouble here is that i need to push `line` to a queue. And that queue is in a function marked `async`. To call a `async` method it says calling method should also be `async`. In that case i end up with an error : `coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor`. so i am confused on how to get this done.

I would want to the log tailing to work as it does with standard linux `tail -f` command. It should not block my Tornado loop from other stuff that is going on (such as web requests, websocket messaging etc etc). I should be abel to send `line` data to any sync or async method in my codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tornado.process.Subprocess` instead of `subprocess.Popen` (and its `STREAM` option instead of `PIPE`). This lets you read from the subprocess asynchronously:

```
async def tail(self, file):
    self.__process = Subprocess(["tail", "-n", "1", "-f", file], stdout=Subprocess.STREAM)
    while True:
        line = await self.__process.stdout.read_until(b"\n")
        do_something(line)

def start_tail(self):
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.tail, self.__log_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ben Darnell. I used your snippet and got this error stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/PWPVdmjF

The logs file has simple text (tomcat like log file)

Comment: nvm, i figured that one with googling : An answer by you :)
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1630

Thanks a lot!